# Regex substitution: find double quotes not following by specific character

Tags: regex, replace, substitution

I have the following situation:

- 3" a
- 3":a
- 3",a
- 3"a
- 3"2
- 3"A

I need to find a replace a double quote with space every time the double quote is not following by : or ,.

So, for my case the expected results will be:

- 3  a
- 3":a
- 3",a
- 3 a
- 3 2
- 3 A

Any idea how write this logic using regex?

Regards,

Comment: In what regex language?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead `A(?!B)` for that. It matches an expression A that is not followed by expression B.
The replacement of the matches with spaces will depend on the used language.

```
"(?![:,])
```

Applied to your examples: https://regex101.com/r/UiPlaC/2

If you want to handle the case `3" a` without having multiple spaces, just include one (or even more?) optional spaces in the match.

```
"(?![:,])\ ?
```

**See here for more information**:

- [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups/2973495#2973495)
- https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html